# Handling blank lines in email headers

Tags: c++, email, mime, thunderbird

Came across a few mails which aren't RFC compliant

```
authentication-results: spf=none (sender IP is ) smtp.mailfrom=**@********.**;

Content-Type: multipart/related;
    boundary="_004_2039b206f2a54788ba6a101978bd3f82DBXPR07MB013eurprd07pro_";
    type="multipart/alternative"
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

For example, the mail above has a blank line in the header (before Content-Type). Libraries which strictly abide by RFC (for example https://github.com/mikel/mail), won;t be able to parse them. Apple Mail, Thunderbird do manage to handle such mails.

Have tried to browse through Thunderbird's codebase, being unfamiliar with C++, I just managed to find https://github.com/mozilla/releases-comm-central/blob/1f2a40ec2adb448043de0ae96d93b44a9bfefcd1/mailnews/mime/src/mimemsg.cpp

Can someone point me to the part of the Thunderbird's codebase where mail parsing happens, or any opensource libraries/apps which handle such non complaint mails.

**EDIT:**

Hexdump of the blank line. It contains a space.

```
00013e0: 2a2a 2a2a 2a2a 2e2a 2a3b 0d0a 200d 0a43  ******.**;.. ..C
00013f0: 6f6e 7465 6e74 2d54 7970 653a 206d 756c  ontent-Type: mul
0001400: 7469 7061 7274 2f72 656c 6174 6564 3b0d  tipart/related;.
```

Comment: I suspect that the `blank` line is not really blank, but has a space on it -- which would make your problem a bug in the ruby implementation, rather than a feature in the other implementations -- could you add an octal/hex dump of the "problem line*

Comment: @Soren Appended the hexdump, the line has a space in it

Comment: So the _blank_ line is in fact a continuation line from the previous header -- the ruby code in `mail` probably `trims` the lines before parsing them -- causing the code to fail the continuation syntax.

Comment: @Soren Yep, its an empty folded header. The uncompliant behaviour was introduced in https://github.com/mikel/mail/commit/17783f8536fc09b926c7425dbacfc35e0e851ef5. The issue was raised in https://github.com/mikel/mail/commit/a2a45597bce66ebe788cedaaab848a37bd04b25a.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ruby code in the referenced [ruby library](https://github.com/mikel/mail) is not confirming to the RFC, which allows multiple lines to be folded into a single header line.  The rule is that a continuation header line (folding headers) should start with a space -- the exact details are in RFC 5322, section ["Folding White Space and Comments"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.2.2).

The most likely problem is that the Ruby code is reading each line and trimming the white spaces before parsing -- thus failing to detect the extra line is in fact belonging to the previous header -- the extra line does however not add anything to the header (as it contains just a space), but it is valid syntax.

**EDIT:**

The non compliant behaviour was introduced in commit [17783f8536fc09b926c7425dbacfc35e0e851ef5](https://github.com/mikel/mail/commit/17783f8536fc09b926c7425dbacfc35e0e851ef5). One of the side effects introduced is splitting the headers & body on an empty folded header

```
CRLF = /\r\n/
white_space = %Q|\x9\x20|
WSP = /[#{white_space}]/

header_part, body_part = raw_source.split(/#{CRLF}#{WSP}*#{CRLF}(?!#{WSP})/m, 2)
```

The issue was raised in commit [a2a45597bce66ebe788cedaaab848a37bd04b25a](https://github.com/mikel/mail/commit/a2a45597bce66ebe788cedaaab848a37bd04b25a), but the consensus was to not break existing behavior.